# CarrierWave's rails image uploader's controller isn't accessible to 'static_pages#home'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, carrierwave, controllers

In order to be able to manage a handful of sample images on my rails app's homepage I created an image uploader using CarrierWave.

The problem I'm having is my image_uploader's controller isn't accessible to the homepage at `root   'static_pages#home'`. Is there a way I can make the uploader's controller accessible to my (mostly) static 'static_pages#home'?

For now the only way I could get it to work is by moving my home page index from `/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` to `/app/views/covers/index.html.erb` and changing the route, but this seems like a poor workaround.

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**

As @Udaykumardas suggested below I created a `app/models/static_page.rb` file containing

```
class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
end
```

but now i get the following error:

> NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home 
>   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

referring to `<% @covers.each do |cover| %>`

Here is my routes info in case it helps

```
  get 'covers/index'
  get 'covers/new'
  get 'covers/create'
  get 'covers/destroy'

  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'account_activations/edit'

  get 'sessions/new' 

  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]

  resources :covers, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

I'm unsure if the bottom line needs to be changed to `resources :static_pages, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]`.  I have tried this and it results in a different error as follows:

> NameError in StaticPagesController#home 
>   undefined local variable or method `new_cover_path'

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Hi @Udaykumardas, do you mean in `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb`?

Comment: @Udaykumardas, Ah, okay, I think I get it.  So basically I just need to rename (or duplicate) the uploader's model to static_pages.rb (snake case I think for rails 4), correct?

Comment: @Udaykumardas The path I want for root is already set as `static_pages#home` as shown above, but it doesn't work because even after creating `models/static_pages.rb` and adding `mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader` it still doesn't have access to the controller, so it gives a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error.

Comment: You should create a model with name `StaticPage.rb` instead of `static_pages.rb`.Model name should be singular.

Comment: Cheers @Udaykumardas, I fixed that but still get `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader` in `StaticPage.rb` file.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and am getting a different error now.  I have updated my question with the details and more info.  Thanks Uday :)